# Has there ever been stock options under hyperinflation?

Tags: econometrics

I believe the most developed example is weimar. I dont think it had any stock options. I dont think there has been any country under hyperinflation with stock options. I wonder how option prices would behave.

Comment: Even if the options existed, who is going to trade them? The bid/offer is likely is going to be extremely wide, and so it’s not really a market.

Comment: Option prices would be affected by change in carry cost due to inflation.